# Why am I getting "Trying to create an instance of an abstract contract." error when I use factory contract pattern?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix

I have 2 contracts : Registry, Factory.
Registry contract is compatible with ERC721 contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721MetadataMintable.sol";

contract Registry is ERC721MetadataMintable {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;

    constructor(
        string _name,
        string _symbol
    ) ERC721MetadataMintable() public payable {
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
    }
}
```

Factory contract is like this below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./Registry.sol";

contract Factory {

    function _createRegistry (
        string _name,
        string _symbol
    ) internal returns (address) {
        return new Registry(_name, _symbol);
    }
}
```

However I get error just like this below:

```
browser/Factory.sol:15:16: TypeError: Trying to create an instance of an abstract contract.
    return new Registry(_name, _symbol);
           ^----------^
browser/ERC721Metadata.sol:28:5: Missing implementation:
constructor (string name, string symbol) public {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract `Registry` inherits from contract `ERC721MetadataMintable`.

Contract `ERC721MetadataMintable` inherits from contract `ERC721Metadata`.

The constructor of contract `ERC721Metadata` takes two `string` parameters as input.

You should therefore make sure to call this constructor in the constructor of contract `Registry`:

```
constructor(
    string _name,
    string _symbol
) ERC721MetadataMintable() ERC721Metadata(_name, _symbol) public payable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked with no error. I should've check all the inheritance relations of those ERC721 contracts. Thank you so much.